# Swift, Alamofire.framework: No such file or directory

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

I am Developing an ios app and everything was going fine and then suddenly i got this error

```
error: /Users/himanshututeja/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/xxxxx-ebvzljjfvuvqcubfgvneealjrdrg/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Alamofire.framework: No such file or directory
```

I deleted the derived data folder of xcode, Still no help. Do anyone know the reason why i am facing this issue?

Comment: Menu "Product" > "Clean". It will clean the references to the old file location.

Comment: Already done 3-4 times, not working.

Comment: You may deleted Alamofire accidentally i think.

Comment: i used cocoapods for it.

Comment: Try to update `cocoapods` to last version.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75916928/15023395
This solution worked for me

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are using `cocoapods` then you should once tried to run `pod setup` and `pod install`. I think just running `pod setup` will work!!

Hope this will help :)

Comment: I did what you said, but I am still getting the same error saying xxx.framework: No such file or directory. I have also put it in the embedded binaries

Answer (score 1):

After you have import all the latest `Alamofire.xcodeproj` you can embedded the framework like explained in this image -  in the General tab / your project target:

[image]