# Xcode error Alamofire.framework: No such file or directory

Tags: swift, alamofire, xcode10

I've been stuck on this problem since yesterday morning and I don't know what else to try. I am using Xcode 10, Swift 4.

Everything was ok, until I tried to use a real iPhone to test my app.

I needed to login on Mac id and I realized I created a kind of new certificate (I am new at it and I don’t know why is that). I realized also there was another expired certificate on key chain access that I deleted (from the previous developer).

I tried to run on the iPhone, Xcode asked me about keychain password, I tried to put the password from my Mac id and it wasn’t it. So I declined. All my problems started then.

First error was:

> Command /bin/sh failed with exit code 1

So I tried to check “Run Script Only When Installing” at Build Phases.

The error changed to:

> libswiftcore :-1: Failed with exit code 1

I tried to reset my password from keychain, unlock and lock it, but no success. Tried also to clean project, move to trash all DerivedData.

I tried to restart macbook and xcode also.

So I decided to update Xcode from 9.4 to 10.

Tried again, same error.

Ok, I gave up, I decided to use only simulators then.

I got a new error: `

> dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/Alamofire.framework/Alamofire

So, I tried to add Alamofire framework at Target, Build Phases, Embedded Frameworks.

Every time I tried something different, I tried do clean project, build and run. Also restarting xcode, locking and unlocking keychain.

New and current error:

```
Copy Alamofire.framework 0.1 seconds
PBXCp /Users/myfolder/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/AppZap-epwtpkbsxrklbvdulvpzvgvgswoh/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Alamofire.framework /Users/zapgrafica/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/AppZap-epwtpkbsxrklbvdulvpzvgvgswoh/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/AppZap.app/Frameworks/Alamofire.framework
    cd /Projetos/Mobile/Ios/trunk/AppZap
    export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    builtin-copy -exclude .DS_Store -exclude CVS -exclude .svn -exclude .git -exclude .hg -exclude Headers -exclude PrivateHeaders -exclude Modules -exclude *.tbd -resolve-src-symlinks /Users/zapgrafica/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/AppZap-epwtpkbsxrklbvdulvpzvgvgswoh/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Alamofire.framework /Users/zapgrafica/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/AppZap-epwtpkbsxrklbvdulvpzvgvgswoh/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/AppZap.app/Frameworks

error: /Users/myfolder/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/AppZap-epwtpkbsxrklbvdulvpzvgvgswoh/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Alamofire.framework: No such file or directory
```

I have tried to uninstall pod, install and update. I tried to clean DerivedData also.

I am opening .xcworkspace not the .xcodeproj.

I have read almost 100 questions and answers from here.

The only thing I realized is that since the first time I declined keychain, I have never gotten the box from keychain with “Always Allow, Decline and Allow” anymore.

Could anyone help me please?

Comment: I used to have the same problem, yet didn't understood why it happened. As far as I know is a problem with your keychain. Try removing the certificate, change the bundle identifier and try it again.

Comment: How can I do that, please? Just deleting iPhone Developer certificate from keychain and then?

Comment: then generate new certificate and change the bundle ident, of the app

Comment: After I delete it, it generates automatically a new certificate with today's date, right? Why do I need to change the bundle identifier, please?

Comment: I told you I don't know, just worked for me. I had the same issue

Comment: It worked. I didn't want to change the bundle identifier, but still did it. It doesnt work. So I came back to previous name, it doesnt work also. So I tried to delete Alamofire that I had added on Embedded Frameworks and from the folders on the left side (because before, when it was working, I didnt have Alamofire like this). I cleaned, build and started to work again. Thank you so much @EneaDume, you saved my life!!

Comment: can I add this as an answer to be accepted

Comment: sure. I voted as useful, dont know how to put as accepted, sorry

Comment: There is an answer by Arslan Kaleem which was deleted by  ChrisF♦ that was the solution for me: [Update CocoaPods to 1.12.1](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/11808#issuecomment-1480802886)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Swift, Alamofire.framework: No such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37657932/swift-alamofire-framework-no-such-file-or-directory)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**UPDATED**

I used to have the same problem, yet didn't understood why it happened. As far as I know is a problem with your keychain. Try removing the certificate, change the bundle identifier and try it again.

**mixed with your solution**

Then, clean and run.

Answer (score 3):

Search for source="$(readlink "${source}")" and replace it with:

```
#    source="$(readlink "${source}")"
source="$(readlink -f "${source}")"
```

Comment: Instead of posting the same answer to more than one question, you should instead vote to close the question as a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

> I got a new error: dyld: Library not loaded:
>   @rpath/Alamofire.framework/Alamofire.

You are on the correct way. Now you must embed Alamofire framework.

Go to project settings -> Select your target -> Build phases -> Embedded Frameworks -> Press + -> Add Alamofire as embedded framework.

Here is a [Link to documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/technotes/tn2435/_index.html) on how to do it.

Comment: I tried it before, didnt work. It worked after removing what I have added at Embedded Frameworks and changing bundle identifier. Thanks @Enea Dume