# ios/Flutter/App.framework" failed: No such file or directory (2) done flutter

Tags: flutter

Hello i have an app that was working fine till yesterday i update flutter SDK .
after the update is finished i tried to build for ios and it fails every time 
with this error :
[image]

i have tried the following :
pod deintegrate 
pod install
pod update
flutter clean 
deleted pod folder
did pod install again 
created new flutter project and copied the files to the new project and its just the same error

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I had the same issue both on `flutter channel stable` with version **1.17.1** and on `flutter channel beta` with version **1.18.0-11.1.pre**.

I copied the `App.framework` from another project under `ios/Flutter` directory and successfully built an iOS release version.

Update 19/May/2020
I opened a issue in flutter since every `flutter clean` removes it so to continue to copy is not a solution. It can be followed [here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/57554)

This is not a working solution because `App.framework` should contain the application compiled code so it should be different for every app. Explanations are available [here](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/add-to-app/ios/project-setup) ( Tip: Flutter.framework is the bundle for the Flutter engine, and App.framework is the compiled Dart code for this project.)

Update 19/May/2020 22:30
The problem is really solved with Flutter team support.
The issue is that in the relevant "Target" under "Build phases" before "Compile sources" we need to have a "Run script" for shell which is running

`/bin/sh "$FLUTTER_ROOT/packages/flutter_tools/bin/xcode_backend.sh" build`

Comment: Thats also is what i did and it worked . Please consider this as the solution for this problem thanks

Comment: How do you add the script to `Compile sources`?

Answer (score 5):

The solution for me was:

Inside: Xcode > Runner > Build Phases tab > Run Script section

a) When deploying to the emulator: **disable** 'Run script only when installing'

b) When deploying a real release: **enable** 'Run script only when installing' [this is only if you get an error]

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Workaround is to update all the generated Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-App/Pods-App-frameworks.sh files to add the -f flag to the call to readlink. In other words, need to replace:

`source="$(readlink "${source}")"`

with

`source="$(readlink -f "${source}")"`

Seems this is CocoaPods issue...

Answer (score 4):

navigate to Pods->Target support files->Pods_runner_framework

go to 44th line

change `source="$(readlink "${source}")"`   **to**   `source="$(readlink -f "${source}")"`

Comment: This worked! Not sure how anyone found this. But this build system sucks!

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if it's related to the original question, but I found a very similar issue when I'm using Bitrise.io as my CI/CD tool for the Flutter project. Turned out I need to make sure that `cocoapods` is already installed.

```sh
gem install cocoapods
```

My complete story can be seen at my Gist here https://gist.github.com/empeje/0efadbad8aa001658dd547efe8233e94

Comment: Thanks! It's definitely a problem with Cocoapods. It happened to me when I deleted XCode cache. What helped me solve this issue was running the following commands: `gem uninstall cocoapods`, `gem install cocoapods`, `gem update --system`.

Answer (score 0):

This happened after i deleted some files on my macbook pro m1 to freeup space, i tried many solutions but only managed to fix it after i deleted the Flutter sdk, then downloaded it again, unzip, follow the installation process then run  flutter pub get , worked fine.