# Missing Library Error in Mac Catalyst when distributed through Testflight

Tags: ios, xcode, ffmpeg, mac-catalyst, ffmpegkit

The iOS version of the app is functioning correctly on TestFlight, and there are no issues when building the Mac Catalyst version of the app from Xcode. However, when distributing the app to TestFlight for Mac Catalyst, the FFmpegkit library fails to load, resulting in a crash. The crash report indicates that the library is missing and cannot be located in the designated file path.

Specifically, the crash report states that the library could not be loaded from "@rpath/ffmpegkit.framework/ffmpegkit". Despite extensive efforts, I have been unable to resolve this issue.

This is error message in the crash report.

Termination Reason: Namespace DYLD, Code 1 Library missing
Library not loaded: @rpath/ffmpegkit.framework/ffmpegkit
Referenced from: <9162F8B0-7112-310B-8EDA-59766087927F> /Applications/MyApp.app/Contents/MacOS/MyApp
Reason: tried: '/System/Library/Frameworks/ffmpegkit.framework/ffmpegkit' (no such file, not in dyld cache), (security policy does not allow @ path expansion)
(terminated at launch; ignore backtrace)

Are there any alternative solutions to resolve this problem?

UPDATE

- I tried Eugene Dudnyk Solutions but I still received the same error
- I checked the package content found in Testflight and the paths are correctly matching the following /System/Library/Frameworks/ffmpegkit.framework/ffmpegkit
- I ran the app scheme as release within Xcode and it build and ran fine with no issues
- I manually loaded the signing certificates for mac catalyst and still getting the error
- Deleted all derived data
- Deleted and reinstalled Xcode and also tried previous Xcode versions.
- Deleted  the project completely

I tried most of the solutions mentioned in this post with no avail.
[iOS app with framework crashed on device, dyld: Library not loaded, Xcode 6 Beta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24333981/ios-app-with-framework-crashed-on-device-dyld-library-not-loaded-xcode-6-beta)

Comment: See if you have the dependency framework added in the Mac Catalyst target.

Comment: @Wo_0NDeRᵀᴹ I tried this but didn't work

Comment: Please update your question with more information about the copying of the framework into the Mac Catalyst app bundle: 1) have you inspected the resulting bundle and ensured that the framework and its binary is actually there? 2) If it's there, have you inspected the `LD_RUNPATH_SEARCH_PATHS` build setting for your app to check if it is actually searching for a framework at the destination where it actually resides?

Comment: @STerrier Do you mean that inside of the package content you have this path: `/System/Library/Frameworks/ffmpegkit.framework/`? Is it like inside of the app, i.e. `MyApp.app/System/Library/Frameworks/ffmpegkit.framework/`, or where?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75916928/15023395 can you please try this solution ?

Comment: @ArslanKaleem tried your solution but it didn't work

Comment: @EugeneDudnyk MyApp.app/System/Library/Frameworks/ffmpegkit.framework/

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, and I found out I accidentally deleted the Hardened Runtime capability for macOS. It must be enabled for macOS. Read more here: [About Hardened Runtime](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/hardened_runtime)

Comment: Thank you!! You saved my skin. My archive / TestFlight version was also not running, and adding Hardened Routine did the trick for me.
Problem was, I created my project as multi-platform, than discovered some code would only run in Mac Catalyst. When doing the change from native to Catalyst, I also deleted Hardened Routine (among others) and the archived Release version would not find my frameworks and run (even if the Debug version ran fine...)

Answer (score 0):

Add to `LD_RUNPATH_SEARCH_PATHS` build setting for Mac Catalyst the following path:

```
@executable_path/../System/Library/Frameworks
```

Alternatively, if you use configuration file for your target, you can add there this:

```
LD_RUNPATH_SEARCH_PATHS[sdk=macosx] = $(inherited) @executable_path/../System/Library/Frameworks
```

Comment: Thanks Eugene but it didn't work

Comment: @STerrier updated answer based on your comments to the question